# Question marked as duplicate of itself

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

What should I do when I see a question marked as a duplicate of itself? I am referring to this question:

[How to validate email address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7839205/1402846)

Comment: Consult [this question][1].


  [1]: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159150/question-marked-as-duplicate-of-itself

Comment: Now its suggested duplicate leads it to a closed question with a suggested duplicate.  Talk about walking up the chain there...

Comment: @Makoto Fixed that, now it points to the former's dupe dupe.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone [manually changed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7839205/revisions) the duplicate notice, and linked the question to itself (probably without realizing it). I just rolled that edit back.

So I'd say, if you ever see something like that again (I never had), check the review history first (if there's no link, go to `stackoverflow.com/posts/POST_ID/revisions`). If it was not a bad edit, flag it for moderator attention with a custom reason, and explain the issue.