# Two SO Questions, each marked as Duplicate of the other

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This is a request for reopening, but under somewhat novel circumstances (probably never to be repeated).  I'm asking for discussion because while researching a SciComp.SE Question, I stumbled upon a pair of SO Questions that were marked duplicates of each other on Aug. 1, 2011:

[How to get a radial(polar) plot using gnu plot? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772135/how-to-get-a-radialpolar-plot-using-gnu-plot)

[How to create a radial plot using gnuplot? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825906/how-to-create-a-radial-plot-using-gnuplot)

It appears that both Questions were closed by a (different) Moderator's action (a little less than 2 hours apart).

Same User asked both Questions (five days apart), and the Accepted Answer on both is by another User (who helpfully points out the duplication at start of second Answer).

I'm thinking we should REOPEN the first copy, which has a useful second Answer.

The second copy can be left marked as duplicate or perhaps deleted as its independent value is slight.

Comment: The possibility to circular close questions as duplicates should be submited as bug anyway....
It should be fixed but obviously it isn't: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop

Comment: @ŁukaszL.: I suspect this could not happen now, at least not through the close voting process.  See also [Question marked as duplicate of itself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159150/question-marked-as-duplicate-of-itself?rq=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I initiated a vote to reopen, and after that aged out, I flagged for moderator attention.

The first (better answered) Question is now reopened!

Comment: Why is this Community Wiki?  What purpose does this answer serve in a Wiki environment?

Comment: @JohnnyBones: I suppose the Answer serves the purpose of recording a resolution, and by posting as Community Wiki I'm inviting anyone (esp. a moderator) to add to the Answer further info.  My impression is there have been one or two other recent cyclic-duplicates reported (of an age consistent with the history/closure of the bug allowing such things).